# Cumulative distribution function of the generalized beta distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $Z$ has a beta distribution on the interval $(0,1)$ and its probability density function is $f_Z(x)$. I know that the cumulative density function is,

$$F_Z(x) = \mathbb{P}(Z \leq x) = \int_{0}^x f_Z(u) \, du.$$

I also know that if $X = cZ$, then $X$ has a beta distribution generalized on the interval $(0,c)$. But what is the cumulative density function of $X$?

$$F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X\leq x) = \mathbb{P}(cZ \leq x) = \, ?$$

It is possible to write this in terms of the pdf or cdf of $Z$?

Comment: The usual name for $F_Z(x)$ is the cumulative *distribution* function of $Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your derivation, wouldn't it be just $\mathbb{P}(cZ \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(Z \leq \frac{x}{c}) = F_Z(\frac{x}{c})$?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Since $f_X(u) = f_Z(\frac{u}{c})$, integrating the left side from $0$ to $x$ should be the same as integrating  $f_Z(t)$ from $t=0$ to $t=\frac{x}{c}$. +1 and accepted (and duh! :D).